# Read questions from a plain text file

Tags: php, text-files

I want to read questions from a text document in PHP and sort them in an `array()`.

The resulting array should look like this:

```
print_r($questionnaire);

array(
      'question 1' => array('yes','no'),
      'question 2' => array('yes','no'),
      'question 3' => array('yes','no'),
      ...etc
)
```

My text document is:

```
question 1?
yes
no
question 2?
yes
no
question 3?
yes
no
```

I am trying this:

```
$txt_doc = $_FILES['txt_doc']['tmp_name'];

$questions_and_answers = array();

$handle = fopen($txt_doc, 'r') or die($txt_doc . ' : CAnt read file');


                $i = 0;
                while ( ! feof($handle) ) 
                {
                    $line = trim(fgets($handle));

                    if(strstr($line, '?'))//its a question
                    {
                        $questions_and_answers[$i] = $line;$i++;
                    }
                    if(!strstr($line, '?'))
                    {
                        $questions_and_answers[$i][] = $line;
                    }                    

                }
```

Comment: Then what happens when you try that? If it isn't doing what you expect, can explain what it's doing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to produce the output you want, you'll need to use the question as an array key in `$questions_and_answers`. If you do this, `$i` becomes unnecessary. You can do the same check for question mark that you're doing, and when you get to a question, create a new key. Then use that key for subsequent lines (answers) until you get to the next question.

```
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $line = trim(fgets($handle));
    if (strstr($line, '?')) {                          // it's a question
        $question = $line;
    } else {                                           // it's an answer
        $questions_and_answers[$question][] = $line;
    }
}
```